# Java - search collection of strings providing the first few characters

Tags: java, search, collections

I have a collection of strings that I want to search providing only the first few characters.

For example, consider the list of strings: [tom, tomaz, alice, tolstoy, john]. The string [to] would result in the list [tom, tomaz, tolstoy].

**Performance** is a major issue here and the list may be very large.

What is the best way to optimize this? Indexes? Sorting? How?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use a database? Some have indexes optimized exactly for this kind of search

Comment: If you can, maybe you can use a trie instead of a collection as it is more suited for this kind of search.

Comment: Tries and dictionary automata are optimal for this task.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what you mean by very large? Give us a rough order of magnitude. And do you expect the collection of strings to be frequently changing or mostly fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trie is the universal solution, as has already been suggested but if you want a lightweight and relatively fast solution with no outside dependencies, simply put all your string into a `TreeSet` and use `tailSet()` to find the first element matching the prefix, then iterate through the tail set until you find a string that doesn't match. (Note: this could even be the first element if none of your strings match the prefix.)

If your list isn't bigger than a couple of thousand strings, this method is good enough in practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a list, your options are limited. It's simply not suited for this sort of thing.

The data structure that does exactly what you're trying to do is called a Trie [(Wikipedia Entry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

A quick google brings up this java implementation from Duke University:
http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/cps108/fall96/joggle/trie/Trie.java

Answer (score 0):

Look into Solr and Lucene.  They do string searching by index or you could write your own as others have suggested.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to arrange your data if searching like this is a priority and it doesn't cause conflicts with your other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list is small enough to keep in memory, I would use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

This will give you a lookup time proportional to the length of your prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this entirely in memory and without any dependencies, here's one quick option:

```
static int MAX_PREFIX = 3;
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public void addItem(String item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PREFIX && i < item.length(); i++) {
        String prefix = item.substring(0, i);
        List<String> matches = map.get(prefix);
        if (matches == null) {
            matches = new ArrayList<String>();
            map.put(prefix, matches);
        }
        matches.add(item);
    }
}

public List<String> getMatches(String prefix) {
    List<String> matches = map.get(prefix);
    return matches == null ? Collections.<String>emptyList() : matches;
}
```

This is going to very fast since it's just a single `Map` lookup to go from your prefix `String` straight to a `List<String>` of your desired results. If your list is so large that it doesn't fit in memory then you'll need to consider going external. As mentioned you might want to look at Lucene for a local index. Or a database, simply index the column and do a `LIKE 'prefix%'` query.

Comment: The memory requirements and insert time of this over a Trie are staggering. That being said, random access time becomes O(1) which is great if you don't care about those and only want the fastest access time.

Comment: I was somewhat making the assumption that the list was known ahead of time, so I did optimize for read access and simplicity. Insert time isn't horrible here though, you can insert about million/second with a max prefix of 3 (I just gave it a try). The longer the max prefix though the worse it gets.

Comment: Time is relative :) A single insert here is prefix_len hash lookups and inserts, whereas in a Trie it's a single insert after traversing prefix_len nodes. This also consumes (prefix_len * size_of_ref) + item_size in memory (minimum, ignoring the hash table itself and key collisions) for each item. Again though, the access time is near O(1) where a Trie worst case is O(n).

Comment: I'm not disagreeing about the advantages of a Trie :) Just providing an alternative that might be suitable to the use case.